# Marker setDraggable for Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

With Leaflet, any suggestions on how to change the draggability of a marker from another event?

For example, I have:

```
marker = (L.marker([0,0], {draggable: true}));
```

Then later I can do such things as:

```
marker.setIcon(myicon).setLatLng(mylatlng).addTo(map);
```

How would I also change draggable to false?  I have multiple markers and I need to toggle the draggability for individual markers, so I also don't want to freeze the whole map.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker

```
marker.dragging.enable();

marker.dragging.disable();
```